# Are the functions here well defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functions, permutations, elementary-functions

Suppose that $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are finite vector spaces of dimension $k$, $l$ and $m$ such that $x\in X$ , $y\in Y$ and $g(x,y)\in Z$. I define a function $\pi:X\times Y\to X\times Y \times Z$ such that

$$\pi(x,y)=\sigma\circ\left( 1_X\times 1_Y \times g(x,y)\right)$$

where $1_X$ is the identity on $X$ and $1_Y$ the identity on $Y$ and $1_X\times 1_Y \times g(x,y):X\times Y\to X\times Y\times Z$ namely $(x,y)\to(x,y,g(x,y))$ where every $(x,y)$ is associated with one $g(x,y)$, namely $g$ is a bijective (and hence injective) function. For simplicity we further assume that the dimension of the vector space $X\times Y$ is $N$. By writing $\pi_i(x,y)$ we refer to the $i$-th vector of $\pi$ such that $\pi_i=\sigma_i\circ\left( 1_X\times 1_Y \times g_i(x,y)\right)$

I want to define a mapping from the space $X\times Y \times Z_i$ to the $j$-th coordinate $z_j\in Z_i$. I define $(\tau_j)_{j\in I}:X\times Y \times Z_i\to Z_j$ such that

$$\tau_j(x,y,z_i)=pr_j\circ\sigma^{-1}_i$$

If $\sigma_i$ serves as a kind of a function that could change the order of the vector $\left(x,y,g_i(x,y)\right)$, could this be a permutation, namely

$$\sigma_i=\begin{pmatrix}(x_1,y_1) & (x_2,y_2) & \cdots & (x_j,y_j) & \cdots & (x_N,y_N)\\
g_1(x_1,y_1) & g_2(x_2,y_2) & \cdots & g_j(x_j,y_j) & \cdots & g_N(x_N,y_N)\end{pmatrix}$$

where $\tau_j$ could return to us only the $j$-coordinate? Is it well defined?

Comment: Hi! Why do you think you could encounter well definition problems?

Comment: @TurquoiseTilt Well, i would say that it is like I need a second opinion. Do you think that my definition seems ok?

Comment: Yah for what I'm seeing you're composing all functions that are well defined, to me this seems fine!

Comment: @TurquoiseTilt Thank you very much for your time! I appreciate that you responded back so soon

Comment: What is $\sigma$? You define all the other maps, including the obvious $1_X, 1_Y$, but toss in $\sigma$ with no explanation at all. Also, you describe $Z$ as just an arbitrary $m$ dimensional vector space, but then start talking about $Z_i, \pi_i, \sigma_i, g_i$ as if these had some obvious interpretation. For an arbitrary vector space $Z$, they do not. Maybe you want $\Bbb R^m$ (or some other scalar field)?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I write only the scemantics... I can not write a full interpretation of everything, trust me I want days...not hours... You could say that they are scalar fields yes. The function $\sigma$ is a permutation. In communication games it is usually defined as above in the sense that it can serve as a simple encryption scheme and every player $j$ who will receive it will learn only her own coordinate of the vector $\pi_i$. Anyway...maybe I make things more difficult to understand...

Comment: It seems apparent that you do not understand what a "vector space" actually is, and falsely assume it will always be $Z = Z_1 \times Z_2 \times \dots$ for some $Z_i$. This is not true. If you want such a structure, you need to say so. If you want $\sigma$ to be a permutation, you also need to say so.

Comment: @PaulSinclair but I say that $\sigma$ is a permutation.....what do you mean I do not understand what a vector space is?

Comment: Ok one thing that I forgot to mention is that the dimension of the spaces must satisfy some condition such that the space $X\times Y$ must be of equal size with $Z$

Comment: I mean you assume all sorts of structure is natively present in vector spaces that in fact is not present, but must be added with care if you have need of it. And you do not say in your post that $\sigma$ is a permutation anywhere. You do call $\sigma_i$ a permutation, but describe it in terms of that supposed structure of your vector space that you failed to establish. Just use $\Bbb R^k, \Bbb R^l, \Bbb R^{k+l}$ instead of $X, Y, Z$. Then all these assumptions you made about the structure will actually be true. And say at the start that $g$ is bijection instead of hiding it in the middle.

Comment: And just how is $Z = \{a,b,c,d\}$ a *vector space*??